# Browser is not read my url

Tags: python, swift, django, xcode

Browser is not read my url.
 I am making Swift app and I wanna make a system in my app which upload a image to my Django server. 
So in this time, when I run emulator(it is iPhone's emulator) of Xcode and I select image and I put "Send" button which send images to the server,I wanna send the image to my server.So,I have to blank localhost:8000.
When I run my server like

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

in my terminal
and wrote this url http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/ (it is my server's url of a page)
in searching box of Google,a browser said ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and nothing is showed.
When I run my server by `python manage.py runserver`,the wrote url was showed in a browser.So I do not know why I cannot access to the page by writing the url.

Comment: You just try `python manage.py runserver` and check which ip address the application is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` is for public port that means you need to access the app using your machines ip, check your machines ip and in url type

```
http://your_ip:8000/admin/accounts/
```

And if you want to access it via localhost :

**run this code in command line(cmd)**:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Then follow this link in browser :

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have access in localhost first write this at cmd :

```
    Python manage.py runserver
```

Then follow this link in browser :

```
   Http://localhost:8000/admin/accounts/
```